# Find and insert text

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I am trying to find all occurrences of header("") in my php project and looking to add error_log("header changed here") or a message like that so I can find out where the header is changing.
Could I get some help on the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
13:06:38 [uu@dhcp-34] cat test.txt
header()

13:06:41 [uu@dhcp-34] cat a.bash
#!/bin/bash

sed -e '/header()/a \
error_log(\"header changed here\")' test.txt

13:06:49 [uu@dhcp-34] ./a.bash
header()
error_log("header changed here")

13:06:58 [uu@dhcp-34]
```

Make sure you have the sed in two lines like the way I have it above, NOT in a single line.

Comment: So I am not looking to substitute but insert after the end of the header statement. Won;t your command replace my header statement?

Comment: Actually it is throwing an error - extra characters after \ at the end of a command, and I want to run a script on my entire project with a lot of files.

Comment: @user1552879 Are you using Linux or some other OS ? I know that for BSD it doesn't work

Comment: I am using a Mac so Linux

Comment: @Mac uses BSD version for sed, so that won't work the same way. You can put it in a script. See my edit.

Comment: what does it complain about ? The script works for me on a Mac ! DO you anything inside `header("is there anything here ?")`

Comment: Yes I do, but to test I am not even using header("some text") but I am just trying to replace a "Random Word". Just silent failure.

Comment: I don't understand why the script doesn't work. See my edit. I have the full thing. Make sure you have the sed command in two lines NOT in  a single line.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste your script and file content ?